# Keep only those rows in a Pandas DataFrame equal to a certain value (paired multiple columns)

Tags: python, pandas

A part of the answer can be found here ([How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)), however it's only for one column. I'm wondering how to apply it for paired values in multiple columns (two in this case).

I have a data frame df where the filtering columns are B and C (NaN represents empty cells):

```
    A     B      C  D
0   1  Blue  Green  4
1   2  Blue  Green  6
2   3  Blue  Green  2
3   4  Blue    NaN  6
4   5  Blue    NaN  9
5   6   NaN  Green  8
6   7  Blue  Green  8
7   8   NaN    NaN  9
8   9   NaN  Green  1
9  10   NaN  Green  2
```

I would only like to keep the rows with respect to B and C for which B='Blue' and C='Green', all the other rows can be dropped, ideally producing:

```
    A     B      C  D
0   1  Blue  Green  4
1   2  Blue  Green  6
2   3  Blue  Green  2
6   7  Blue  Green  8
```

Any ideas?

Code for the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], "B": ['Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue', 'Blue','Blue', np.nan, 
'Blue', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], "C": ['Green', 'Green', 'Green', np.nan, np.nan, 'Green', 'Green', 
np.nan, 'Green', 'Green'], "D": [4,6,2,6,9,8,8,9,1,2]})
print(df)
```

Comment: It is in second answer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296878/2901002)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the multi-condition option earlier there. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, it is common dupe question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is the `&` operator:

```
df[(df['B']=='Blue') & (df['C']=='Green')]
```

Comment: If there are many columns, is there any way to do it in a quick way?